# How to show database record in div with good looking row by row separated by " | "

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have show data record from db but can't good style, i want show that row by row with separated by " | ", one to many relationship data record.

```
<?php
                $kolom = 4;
                $i = 1;
                $mysqli = new mysqli("x", "y", "z", "a");
                $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM daftar_penawaran ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 4");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    if (($i) % $kolom == 1){
                        echo '<div class="row">';
                    }
                    echo '<div class="smart-column-compact wide25-compact">
                    
                    <div class="boxmodeloffer" style="width:100%;">
                    <div class="w3-black">
                    <h3 style="padding:15px;">'.$row['JudulPenawaran'].'</h3>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="" style="padding:10px;">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail class="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right" src="'.$row['Gambar'].'" width="100%" height="150px"/>
                    <label class="smart-bottom-border">'.$row['isipenawaran'].'</label><br>
                    <i class="bi bi-person-fill" style="padding-right:5px;"></i><span>
                    <label>'.$row['Penerbit'].'</label><br>
                    <label id="getnomerpenawaran" style="padding-right:5px;">'.$row['NoPenawaran'].'</label><span><label>'.$row['Timestamp'].'</label></span>
                    </div>
                    
                    <a href="offerdetail.php" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:10px;">Detail</a>
                    </div></div>';
                    
                    if (($i) % $kolom == 0){
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                    $i++;
                }?>
```

Comment: If you don't want to use a regular `<table>`, first make sure that you know the maximum length of all the data for each specific column that can be returned. Then use [str_pad()](https://www.php.net/str_pad). It allows you to set a static length for each data cell so you can separate them with pipeline characters.

Comment: @AndrewL64 is the way I display the data correct?

Comment: Take a look at [printf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf) which is very nice for formatting.